# Calculating $17^{14}\mod{71}$ using Fermat's little theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Calculate $17^{14} \pmod{71}$

By Fermat's little theorem:
$17^{70} \equiv 1 \pmod{71}$
$17^{14} \equiv 17^{(70\cdot\frac{14}{70})}\pmod{71}$

And then I don't really know what to do from this point on. In another example, the terms were small enough that I could just simplify down to an answer, but in this example, I have no idea what to do with that $17^{(70\cdot\frac{14}{70})}$

What do I do from here?

Comment: Why not square it out once? $ 17^2 =289 \equiv 5 \pmod{71} $ so you need $ 5^7 \pmod{71} $. A bit of calculation gives $ 5^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{71}.$

Comment: Little Fermat only helps, when the exponent is large (in comparison to the modulus). Search for something else from your toolbox.

Comment: @RagibZaman How did you get $5^7$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Do you mean Fermat's wont work on this problem or that there is an easier way?

Comment: Fermat is true, but the point of using it is to subtract an integer multiple of 70 from the exponent. I fail to see how that would help in this case. The others have already shown how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$17$ isn’t particularly close to a multiple of $71$, but as Ragib Zaman pointed out, $17^2=289$ is: $289=4\cdot71+5$. Thus, $17^{14}=(17^2)^7=289^7\equiv 5^7\pmod {71}$. At that point you can use brute force, or you might notice that $5^4=625$ is pretty close to $9\cdot71=639$. In fact $625=639-14$, so $5^4\equiv -14\pmod{71}$, $5^5\equiv -70\equiv 1\pmod{71}$, and finally $$17^{14}\equiv 5^7\equiv 5^2\equiv 25 \pmod{71}\;.$$

Comment: ahhh, I didnt know you could square it like that, but it certainly makes sense that you can. thanks

Comment: @BrianMScott How did you go from $5^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{71}$ to $25 \pmod{71}$?

Comment: @Arvin: $5^7=5^5\cdot 5^2\equiv 1\cdot25\pmod {71}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$
17^{14}\equiv 17^{70} \cdot 17^{14} \equiv 17^{84}
$$

or

$$
17^{14}\equiv 17^{-70} \cdot 17^{14} \equiv 17^{-56}
$$

I don't see any of these as especially easy to calculate, as $17^{14} = 289^{7} \equiv 5^{7}$. If you don't have to use Fermat's, I'd suggest going with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the computation using an [addition chain.](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/addition_chain.html)

$\qquad 17^2\: \equiv\ 5$

$\qquad 17^3\: \equiv\ 17\cdot 17^2\:\equiv\ 5\cdot 17\ \equiv\ 14$

$\qquad 17^5\: \equiv\ 17^2\cdot 17^3\: \equiv\ 5\cdot 14\ \equiv\: -1$

$\qquad 17^7\: \equiv\ 17^2\cdot 17^5\: \equiv\ 5\:(-1)\ \equiv\: -5$

$\qquad 17^{14} \equiv\ 17^7\cdot 17^7\: \equiv\ (-5)^2\: \equiv\ 25$

See the leftmost path in the tree below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this curious problem, the subgroup of order 5 of $(Z_{71}^*, \cdot)$ is formed by these 5 numbers (5 equivalence classes modulo 71):

$$ \{1, 5, 25, -17, -14\} $$

(When multiplying two, another one comes out of the same subgroup).

This group is isomorphic to the group $ (Z_5, +) $ and contains 4 generators.

The 4 different elements of 1 are generators of $\{1, 5, 25, -17, -14\}$

Using (-17) as a generator of the subgroup of order 5, gives us this order:

$$[1, -17, 5, -14, 25]$$

So that:

$$ 5 ^ 3 = -17 $$
$$(-17) ^ 2 = 5$$
$$(17) ^ {14} = (-17) ^ {14} = (-17)^{14 (mod \space 5)} = (-17) ^ 4 = 25$$